# Register-ScheduledJob "completed" but not "running" script as intended

Tags: powershell

## Background

I have a powershell script that is designed to watch a folder for new files using Register-ObjectEvent.

I can get it to run in ISE and PowerShell console just fine.  It works exactly as intended.  It watches the folder and does its job.

### The Script That is Scheduled with Register-ScheduledJob

Here is the .ps1 in full for if it helps:

```
$HomeStatus = 'C:\status'
$mFilter = '*.*'

gci $HomeStatus -Recurse | sort LastWriteTime -desc | select -Skip 1 | Remove-Item -Force

$WatchProps = @{
    Path = $HomeStatus
    Filter = $mFilter
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]"FileName"
    IncludeSubdirectories = $False   
}

$Watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher -Property $WatchProps

$isCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher Created -SourceIdentifier HomeStatus -Action{
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
    gci $HomeStatus -Recurse | sort LastWriteTime -desc | select -Skip 1 | Remove-Item -Force
}
```

### Creating the Register-ScheduledJob

I went ahead and used Register-ScheduledJob to make it run at startup:

```
$startTrigger = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup -RandomDelay 00:01:30 #create trigger for 90 seconds after startup

Register-ScheduledJob -Trigger $startTrigger -FilePath C:\Users\x\Powershell\HomeStatus.ps1 -Name CamHomeStatus
```

That creates the job in task scheduler just fine.  I went ahead and modified the permissions in task scheduler so it runs as SYSTEM with the highest privileges:

[image]

## The Problem

The issue is that it seems to execute the scheduled job just fine, but the script isn't running/working in the background.

I have tested it - first by rebooting the machine and then by running the task on demand.  From the History tab in task scheduler, it appears to be executing without a problem:

[image]

Get-Job returns the following:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Job

    Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
    --     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
    1      CamHomeStatus   PSScheduledJob  Completed     True            localhost            $HomeStatus = 'C:\User...
```

But that isn't what I see if I simply run the .ps1 from ISE or PS console.  When I manually execute the script from either of those options, I see the following:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Job

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
5      HomeStatus                      Running       True                                 ...
```

So to me it looks like the task scheduler runs the scheduled job just fine, but the once the scheduled job runs, it doesn't allow the Register-ObjectEvent job from the .ps1 to start/continue running.

Did I invoke the script incorrectly when I registered the job, or did I miss some argument that allows the script to run after the scheduled job initializes it?

Comment: Are you sure that the job hasn't simply completed before you check it when it runs at startup? I'm not seeing any loops or anything that would keep it running for very long.

Comment: I have a suspicion that it is just running through the code once and then filing it under "complete".  What has me confused is when I run the script via ISE or PS console, the event watcher is persistent and stays open.  I'm pretty novice with PS, so it could be the fault of the script.  I just can't figure out why it would run persistently from ISE but fail to re-create that same behavior when run as a scheduled task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was entirely a Task Scheduler problem and nothing to do with the PowerShell scripts.

1. The Register-ObjectEvent needed the task to stay open.  This was achieved by adding the -NoExit flag in the actions for the task
2. I needed to modify the actions to have not only -NoExit, but also -NoProfile, and -ExecutionPolicy Bypass.  Discovered this following this article: http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Task-Scheduler/

I also switched from the default -Command flag that Register-ScheduledJob uses to the -File flag.

So.. at the end of the day, this is what my Scheduled Task Actions Tab looked like:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\x\Powershell\HomeStatus.ps1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just log the hell out of it:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    $HomeStatus = 'C:\status'
    $mFilter = '*.*'
)

Start-Transcript C:\Temp\CamHomeStatus_Log.txt

Write-Verbose "`$HomeStatus = `"$HomeStatus`""
Write-Verbose "`$mFilter = `"$mFilter`""

$ItemsToRemove = Get-ChildItem $HomeStatus -Recurse | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1
foreach ( $Item in $ItemsToRemove ) {
    Write-Verbose "Removing item `"$($Item.FullName)`""    
    try {
        $Item | Remove-Item -Force
    } catch {
        Write-Warning "An error occurred removing `"$($Item.FullName)`""
        Write-Error $_
        throw
    }
}

Write-Verbose "Creating FileSystemWatcher object"
try {
    $WatchProps = @{
        Path = $HomeStatus
        Filter = $mFilter
        NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]"FileName"
        IncludeSubdirectories = $False   
    }
    $Watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher -Property $WatchProps
} catch {
    Write-Warning "An error occured creating FileSystemWatcher object"
    Write-Error $_
    throw
}

Write-Verbose "Registering ObjectEvent"
try {
    $isCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher Created -SourceIdentifier HomeStatus -Action{
        $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
        $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
        $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
        Get-ChildItem $HomeStatus -Recurse | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Remove-Item -Force
    }
} catch {
    Write-Warning "An error occured registering ObjectEvent"
    Write-Error $_
    throw
}

Stop-Transcript
```

---

```
$startTrigger = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup -RandomDelay 00:01:30 #create trigger for 90 seconds after startup

Register-ScheduledJob -Trigger $startTrigger -FilePath C:\Users\x\Powershell\HomeStatus.ps1 -Name CamHomeStatus -ArgumentList @{ Verbose=$true }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give that a shot and report back with what I get.

Comment: `Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20160816091140
Username: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
RunAs User: WORKGROUP\SYSTEM
Machine: BEAM (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.10586.0)
Host Application: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Version 5.0 -s -NoLogo -NoProfile
Process ID: 10596
PSVersion: 5.0.10586.494
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0.10586.494
BuildVersion: 10.0.10586.494
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20160816091140`

Comment: So basically, no errors are thrown from the script.

Comment: @eko I might have specified the verbose wrong, but it should be outputting more information than that so you can see how far into the script you're getting.

Comment: @eko does Task Scheduler still show it successfully running when the throws are in place?

Comment: Yes, Task Scheduler still reports "Task completed" in the History tab when running it with the logging additions you suggested.  The log above is what it spit out when I manually ran the task in scheduler.

Comment: There would be information between ...1.1.0.1 and Windows PowerShell transcript end End Time:... so it reported that nothing was output. I might have screwed up how to pass in verbose. Try changing all Write-Verbose to Write-Host.

Comment: Makes sense. Just made your recommended switch.  When I run from ISE: `$HomeStatus = "C:\Users\x"
$mFilter = "*.*"
Creating FileSystemWatcher object
Registering ObjectEvent` and then when I ad hoc run the task in scheduler I get identical outputs in the log `$HomeStatus = "C:\Users\x"
$mFilter = "*.*"
Creating FileSystemWatcher object
Registering ObjectEvent`

Comment: So when I run powershell as the NT SYSTEM user `psexec -i -s Powershell.exe` and then run `Get-Job` and `Get-ScheduledJob` Powershell returns absolutely nothing.  It makes me think this is less about the script and more about incorrect properties or user perms in the task itself.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It turned out to be entirely an issue with the Task Scheduler.  I had to add the -NoExit flag to keep the task open.  I also had to add the -NoProfile and -ExecutionPolicy Bypass flags.  Lastly, I had to use the -File flag to point at the .ps1 instead of the -Command flag that Register-ScheduledJob uses.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help to someone. Killed two days trying to solve the same problem:

- Works great from IDE
- Works great run manually
- Doesn't work while running from Task scheduler
  Solution make $glogal: external variables used inside -Action{

You should update:

```
$global:HomeStatus = 'C:\status'

gci $global:HomeStatus -Recurse | sort LastWriteTime -desc | select -Skip 1 | Remove-Item -Force
```

To work it from Task scheduler